# Principled shader is not appearing for me. Where is it?

Tags: shaders

I'm trying to create a text based fire animation but principled is not in my shader options and I'm already in cycles render. I'm using v2.76 (Best my pc will allow). Is it located elsewhere or do i need to use an alternative? And if so, what would that be?

Comment: Are you saying you cannot get 2.79? I think that would be best if you can. I am seeing it in the 2.79 manual, but don't see references for it in 2.76.

Comment: Principled was introduced in 2.79

Comment: No. I don't believe I can get that version. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Could you try explaining in more detail why your computer cannot run blender 2.79? Could you list some specs? What happens when you try running 2.79?

Comment: My cpu is old and isn't compatible with 2.79, 2.79b or 2.8. Nothing above 2.76 will work.